# Ambiguous column error creating table in Aster Studio 6.0

Tags: join, teradata

I am new to databases and am posting a problem from work. I am creating a table in Aster Studio 6.0, but got an error about an ambiguous column. I ran the same query in Teradata SQL Assistant and did not get an error.

I have six tables with millions of rows named EDW.SWIFTIQ_TRANS_DTL, EDW.SWIFTIQ_STORE, EDW.SWIFTIQ_PROD, EDW.STORE_XREF, EDW.TDLNX_STR_OUTLT, and EDW.SURV_CWC.

EDW represents the original database, but the columns were labeled with aliases.

I did a `trim()` on the `VARCHAR` columns for saving spool space. For the error about TDLNX_RTL_OUTLT_NBR, I performed an `INNER JOIN` on similar columns from two different tables. Doing a preview in SQL Assistant, there was a temporary table with only one column called TDLNX_RTL_OUTLT_NBR.

Here’s the SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table_name

DISTRIBUTE BY HASH (SRC_SYS_PROD_ID) AS (

SELECT * FROM load_from_teradata(

ON public.load_from_teradata_dummy

TDPID(‘database_name')

USERNAME(’user_name')

PASSWORD(’ss')

QUERY ('SELECT e.TDLNX_RTL_OUTLT_NBR, e.OUTLT_ST_ADDR_TXT, e.STORE_OUTLT_ZIP_CD, d.TRANS_ID, d.TRANS_DT,

d.TRANS_TM, d.UNIT_QTY, d.SRC_SYS_STORE_ID, d.SRC_SYS_PROD_ID, d.SRC_SYS_NM, a.SRC_SYS_STORE_ID, a.SRC_SYS_NM, a.STORE_NM,

a.CITY_NM, a.ZIP_CD, a.ST_cd, p.SRC_SYS_PROD_ID, p.SRC_SYS_NM, p.UPC_CD, p.PROD_ID, f.SRC_SYS_STORE_ID, f.SRC_SYS_NM,

f.TDLNX_RTL_OUTLT_NBR, g.SURV_CWC_WSLR_CUST_PARTY_ID, g.AGE_CD, g.HIGH_END_ACCT_FLG, g.RACE_ETHNC_CD, g.OCCPN_CD

FROM EDW.SWIFTIQ_TRANS_DTL d

INNER JOIN EDW.SWIFTIQ_STORE a

    ON trim( a.SRC_SYS_STORE_ID) = trim(d.SRC_SYS_STORE_ID)

INNER JOIN EDW.SWIFTIQ_PROD p

    ON trim(p.SRC_SYS_PROD_ID) = trim(d.SRC_SYS_PROD_ID)

    and p.SRC_SYS_NM = d.SRC_SYS_NM

INNER JOIN EDW.STORE_XREF f

    ON trim(f.SRC_SYS_STORE_ID) = trim(a.SRC_SYS_STORE_ID)

INNER JOIN EDW.TDLNX_STR_OUTLT e

    ON trim(e.TDLNX_RTL_OUTLT_NBR)= trim(f.TDLNX_RTL_OUTLT_NBR)

INNER JOIN EDW.SURV_CWC g

    ON g.SURV_CWC_WSLR_CUST_PARTY_ID = e.WSLR_CUST_PARTY_ID

WHERE TRANS_DT between ''2015-01-01'' and ''2015-03-31''')

num_instances('4') ) );
```

ERROR: column reference 'TDLNX_RTL_OUTLT_NBR' is ambiguous.

**EDIT:** Forgot to include a description about the table aliases. a stands for EDW.SWIFTIQ_STORE, p for EDW.SWIFTIQ_PROD, f for EDW.STORE_XREF, e for EDW.TDLNX_STR_OUTLT, g for  EDW.SURV_CWC, and d for EDW.SWIFTIQ_TRANS_DTL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the same error when you try `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` in Teradata. There are three column names, `SRC_SYS_NM` & `SRC_SYS_PROD_ID` & `SRC_SYS_STORE_ID`, which are used multiple times (with different table aliases) within the SELECT.

Add column aliases to make those names unique, e.g. `trans_SRC_SYS_NM` instead of `d.SRC_SYS_NM`.

Additionally the TRIMs in the joins are a very bad idea. You will probably not save that much spool, but force the optimizer to redistribute all spools for join-preparation.

Comment: I made an edit because I forgot to describe the table aliases. The d stands for the table alias. Shouldn't SELECT take the column from the specific table in d.SRC_SYS_NM.

Comment: Of course it will take that specific column. But when you try to create a table it will use this (`SRC_SYS_NM` without the `d.`) as column name and if the same name is used multiple times you get an error as you can't have two columns with the same name in the same table. Btw, the aliases were already in your query...

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense about the multiple columns with the same names being created in the table. Do I need to give the same alias to all columns of the same name? I am having a hard time understanding what the new SELECT statement would look like.

Comment: I misspelled one of the column names in the original post, now there are four column names used multiple times within the SELECT.

Comment: @ScottDavis: You need to assign a *unique* name to each column, e.g. `d.SRC_SYS_NM as trans_SRC_SYS_NM, p.SRC_SYS_NM as prod_SRC_SYS_NM`

Comment: I assigned each column to an alias in the SELECT statement and didn't get an error anymore. Thank you @dnoeth